# Sum of number using user entered 4 digit numbers

Tags: c#, sum-of-digits

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;

    namespace Assignment_1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                double SurfaceArea, Height, Radius, Volume;
                string inputString;
                int number;

                {
                    //Title Text
                    Console.WriteLine("Cylinder - Surface area and volume calculator");

                    //Prompts for input request

                    Console.Write("Enter the radius: ");
                    inputString = Console.ReadLine();

                    //displays user input for radius

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", inputString);

                    Radius = double.Parse(inputString);
                    Console.Write("Enter Height: ");
                    inputString = Console.ReadLine();
                    Height = double.Parse(inputString);

                    //displays user input for height

                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", inputString);

                    //Calculation and display of surface area

                    SurfaceArea = (((2 * ((3.149)) * Radius) + (((2 * (3.149)) * (Radius) * Height))));
                    Console.WriteLine("Surface Area = {0}", SurfaceArea);

                    //Calculation and display of volume

                    Volume = ((3.149 * Radius * Radius * Height));
                    Console.WriteLine("The Volume = {0}", Volume);

                } 

                //Prompt the user for a four digit number (e.g. 5297) and display the sum of all of the digits
                //The four digit number must be read as a single number and the individual digits must be broken out using div (/) and mod (%).

    //Adds white space between lines
                Console.WriteLine("");

                Console.WriteLine("Sum of the digits - enter four digit whole numbers");
                Console.Write("please enter four digit whole number: ");
```

**// At this point i'm confused as to what i should do to get a 4digit number where the number cannot equal zero, be a decimal or be a negative number, cannot be less than 1000 or greater than 9999 i'm not asking for answers because this is for class but some guidance would be helpful**

```
            {
                //Prompt the user for three numbers and display the largest number. Use Math.Max in your solution. 
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it can't be decimal, don't use `double.Parse` - use `int.Parse` instead (or `int.TryParse`, even). Then you can easily check for numbers being less than 1000 or more than 9999 with normal `if` statements...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're two simple ways to solve the problem:

1. You can use *regular expressions*: 4 digits, first one in [1..9] range
2. You can *try parse* user string into int, and if parsing succeeds, *check* if result *within [1000..9999] range*

P.S. As you've asked, I've refrained from coding

Comment: 3. Check if `Length` is 4 and each character `IsDigit`. But 2. seems most appropriate here.

Comment: @Corak: you should also check if the 1st character in ['1'..'9'] range.

Comment: Yes, missed that. firstChar not `'0'`.

Comment: thanks for the help guys Dimitry your solution to my problem seems to be the most efficient i'll try and use that